# Converting magento's products page categories to layered categories

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

So I've been searching for a way to convert the usual magneto 1.9 product page to Layered navigation as shown in this picture: 
Layered Categories
[image]

But I haven't really found a proper procedure online.  Either it's outdated or redundant.  Anyone here could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add your screen shot to post, instead of adding link to image. read this for learn about adding images.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation points to show an image. So i cant do that as yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set '**Is Anchor**' to '**yes**' and you'll get layered navigation.

[image: Set 'is Anchor to yes']